# SELECT DISTINCT or array_unique?

Tags: php, mysql, distinct, array-unique

What do you think is faster?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM myTable;
```

Then fetch to `$myArray`.

Or

```
SELECT user_id FROM myTable;
```

Then fetch to `$myArray` and do

```
$myArray = array_unique($myArray);
```

**Note:** user_id is a **FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For speed and memory efficiency, you want to return the minimum amount from the database without putting unnecessary rows for processing/memory efficiency.  So, the distinct in this case is the better choice.

Comment: +1 As a rule of thumb, if MySQL can do it, it's typically faster and more efficient.